# Can I preview List & Label reports in my WinForm applicaiton?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, report, preview, listlabel

We have been developing a Desktop application in Visual C++ using MFC. There is a generate report module and we decided to use *[*List and Label Reporting Tool**](https://www.combit.com/).

**Issue:** Once the report is generated, we can't preview those generated reports in WinForm. In order to preview this it directs is to List and Label desktop previewer. Like shown in the image below. What approach should I take in order to preview this report in my WinForm?

[image: List-Label]

**Studied resources:**

- https://docu.combit.net/net/en/Tutorial.html
- https://www.combit-support.net/docs/ll/en/combit-listlabel-programmers-manual.pdf

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. When done you should be able to understand that a [mcve] is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know you can use the API [LlPreviewDisplay](https://docu.combit.net/progref/en/Documents/llpreviewdisplay.htm) to open/show preview files within your application.

The other way for more integration could be to use the available OCX control for showing such preview files. Take a look at the documentation of the programmers reference at [Displaying a Preview File](https://docu.combit.net/progref/en/index.html#!Documents/displayingapreviewfile.htm) and [The Viewer OCX Control](https://docu.combit.net/progref/en/#!Documents/theviewerocxcontrol.htm). As I know of List & Label also a lot of programming samples are installed to see how it works in detail.

btw: cannot comment - to less reputations for that as newbie.

Comment: Thanks, This is really helpful. Still getting familiar with all the event handle. There seems to be very little resources other than programmers manual.